# How to resume stopped job on a remote machine given pid?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a process on a machine which I stopped (with a Ctrl-Z). After ssh'ing onto the machine, how do I resume the process?

Comment: To clarify the question, you might note that you are trying to do this from a *different* shell, and that you have no remote-desktop-style accesss, etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will need to find the PID and then issue `kill -CONT <pid>`.

You can find the PID by using `ps` with some options to produce extended output.  Stopped jobs have a `T` in the `STAT` (or `S`) column.

If you succeed in continuing the process but it no longer has a controlling terminal (and it needs one) then it could possibly hang or go into a loop: just keep your eye on its CPU usage.

Comment: This (`kill -CONT ...`) is the right trick in general, but beware of two more things: (1) This will slightly confuse its parent shell (let's call this *P* for Parent), which gets no notice that the process (let's call it *T*, for sTopped) has been continued so *P* thinks *T* is still stopped. (2) If the process *T* *is* still attached to its controlling terminal and tries to do certain "tty ops", the shell will not have transferred the *terminal*'s control group info and *T* will immediately stop again with `SIGTTIN` or `SIGTTOU`.

Comment: At this point, it's probably a good idea to mention `screen` or `tmux`.

Answer (score 10):

[You can type in `fg` to resume process.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fg_%28Unix%29)  If you have multiple processes, you can type `fg processname`, (e.g. `fg vim`) or `fg job_id`.

To find out the job id's, use the `jobs` command.

Relevant quote from wikipedia on what it does:

> fg is a job control command in Unix and Unix-like operating systems that resumes execution of a suspended process by bringing it to the foreground and thus redirecting its standard input and output streams to the user's terminal.

Comment: fg needs the job number. I'm trying to do this remotely.

Comment: type in `jobs` to get the list of jobs

Comment: @jh314: `jobs` is a shell built in (necessarily so, as the job numbers are local to that process) so he'd have to have access to the terminal on which the shell is running, negating the need for a "non-shell" resume.  This is possible if you set things up in advance (e.g., using `screen`) or have remote desktop access, but he's trying to do it without those.

Answer (score 2):

To find out job-id and pid, use "jobs -l", like this:

```
$ jobs -l
[1]+  3729 Stopped                 vim clustertst.cpp
```

The first column is job_id, and the second is pid.